A movie about army survivors who escape to India
I watched this movie about 2 years ago. It is not that old (not more than 10 years old). 
In this movie there are about some 6 or 7 US Army (not sure) survivors who first escape from Russia to Mongolia, then to China (not sure) and then finally to India. I think at the time of storyline India just got independence (not sure).
I also remember some couple of scenes from the same movie. In one scene when these army survivors were passing from a village they faced mosquito problem. One of these survivors learnt something from a villager that putting on some herbal thread around neck would repel mosquitos. 
In another scene, when these survivors were passing from desert, they also had one girl (maybe she was also one of the survivors). The travel distance was very large and weather was very hot and dry. After going at some distance in desert area the water they had  was gone and the girl unfortunately died. 

The Way Back from 2010 with Ed Harris, Colin Farrell and Saoirse Ronan as the teenage girl.

In 1941, three men reach India from Tibet, having walked 4000 miles after escaping a Siberian gulag. The film tells their story and that of four others who escaped with them and a teenage girl who joins them in flight. The group's natural leader is Janusz, a Pole condemned by accusations secured by torturing his wife; he knows how to live in the wilds. They escape under cover of a snowstorm: a cynical American, a Russian thug, a comic accountant, a pastry chef who draws, a priest, and a Pole with night blindness. They face freezing nights, lack of food and water, mosquitoes, an endless desert, the Himalayas, and moral questions of when to leave someone behind.

Here's the trailer:




Great and very underrated movie.

Yes. This was the movie. Thanks sir.
